# (Python) How can I make a progam that calculates how many days someone has been alive?

Tags: python

Im new to python and im wondering if someone could help me make a program that calculates your days alive from a date of birth. I do not want to use the datetime library. Any help would be really appreciated!

This is what I have got so far:

```
date_of_birth = (input("Enter Date of Birth (YYYY/MM/DD):"))
now_date = ("2021/09/11")

days = date_of_birth[8:10]
months = date_of_birth[5:7]
years = date_of_birth[0:4]


if len(date_of_birth) == 10:
    print ("Working")
else:
    print ("Invalid date of birth")
```

Comment: Technically there are a few months more to count but you would have to decide how many weeks after conception a foetus is considered alive and then how many weeks of gestation the mother went through before birth.  Ignoring that technicality, you only need to count days from the birth date to today which can easily be done using the datetime module.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse a date string into a `datetime` object:

```
import datetime
birthdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(birthdate_str, '%Y/%m/%d')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Then subtraction between two `datetime` objects returns a `timedelta` object, from which you can read the `days` attribute:

```
print((now - birthdate).days)
```

EDIT:

To do it without the `datetime` library, you can convert a date to number of days (i.e. since 0/0/0) and do the arithmetic subtraction:

```
def date_to_days(y, m, d):
    monthDays = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    n = y * 365 + d
    for i in range(m):
        n += monthDays[i]
    l = y # leap days count
    if m <= 2: l -= 1
    l = l // 4 - l // 100 + l // 400
    n += l
    return n

def date_diff(y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2):
    return date_to_days(y2, m2, d2) - date_to_days(y1, m1, d1)
```

Comment: Thankyou! However is there any way to do this without datetime library?